# Unique common column in two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, triggers

I had to ensure in a php and mysql application that 2 different tables A and B, having a common document_number column that this column is unique in a union all between these 2 tables meaning it's values must appear in unique and consecutive order example:

```
   1. I make A document I give number=1
   2. I make A document I give number=2
   3. I make B document I give number=3
   4. I make A document I give number=4
```

I have made a N (Numbers) table with just one column number and I have used before insert and after delete triggers on A and B to insert/delete the document number in the N table. Number is primary key of table N so it is also unique! What am I missing? Should I also make the column document number in A and B as foreign key to point to number in Numbers ? Please help.

Table A has id, number, date, client_id. We obtain table A from several D documents. We have ADetails=A_ID, D_ID. D modifies the stock.
Table B has id, number, date, client_id, value.
Table B already existed and modified stock by itself. DDetails and BDetails have product, quantity and value.
Tables B and D have similar fields but have different number range and are different entities. Table A, B, D and their details tables have already been implemented as different tables.

So I have made a table Numbers with a primary key number in which I copy the number from A and B with triggers. Update on the number column in A and B is not allowed.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE or replace TRIGGER `before_insert_trigger_A`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `A`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into `numbers` values (NEW.number);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE or replace TRIGGER `before_insert_trigger_B`
BEFORE INSERT
ON `B`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into `numbers` values (NEW.number);
END$$
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE or replace TRIGGER `after_delete_trigger_A`
AFTER DELETE
ON `A`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
delete from `numbers` where `number`=OLD.number
   and not exists ( select 1 from B where `number`=OLD.number);
END$$
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE or replace TRIGGER `after_delete_trigger_B`
AFTER DELETE
ON `B`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
delete from `numbers` where `number`=OLD.number
   and not exists ( select 1 from A where `number`=OLD.number);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `but they have 2 different behaviours so one must modelate them separately`...if they share mostly the same columns of data they can still be in the same table, you can just add a "type" column to differentiate them. And then this UNION problem disappears

Comment: @ADyson You can imagine an invoice with 2 behaviours: one alters stock directly (B) and in the other case a child document has already altered the stock and A is just a header for these child documents.

Comment: Not sure I follow you to be honest, no. It's not my data, after all

Comment: This is a classic example for single table inheritance when you store the different classes in one table as @ADyson has already suggested. You are complicating your design with multiple tables. The alternative would be to have a common table with id column and a few other common columns and store the different properties in their own tables

Comment: Linked two already exiating questions discussing inheritance in mysql, choose the design that best fits your business requirements

Comment: I read your modified question again, but I must say you make things complicated, and it's not really clear why. To me it seems you are trying to have documents with an unique document number, so make a table called "documents" with a column containing that unique number. That's all you need. No triggers, no A and B or D tables.

Comment: @KIKO Software Thanks for trying. The application is already made and I have made Numbers the parent in place of documents table for unicity purposes. Making a Documents common table would mean erasing half of an already made application. D table is a must so A the header (parent) becomes a must too. Thanks again sincerely for reading and trying.